# Arity Mismatch: where to put parameter

Tags: scheme

With my code I need to use multiple functions and combine them into one that will evaluate to the nth prime number between a and b. The functions I need to use are `gen-consecutive` `filter` `value-at-position`.

The problem with my code is that with the function `gen-consecutive` requires 3 parameters a function (f) and a and b which acts as a range, and I am not sure where to put the `f` argument in my `nth-prime-between` function. 
I keep getting the error "gen-consecutive: arity mismatch" and that it expected 3 arguments (f a b) instead of just 2 arguments (a b)

Here is my code:

```
(define (nth-prime-between a b n)
   (value-at-position filter prime? (gen-consecutive a b)) n)
```

Here is the other functions:

```
(define (gen-consecutive f a b)
  (if (>  a b)
      '()
      (cons (f a) (gen-consecutive f (+ a 1) b))))

(define (filter f lst)
   (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((f (car lst))
         (cons (car lst) (filter f (cdr lst))))
        (else
         (filter f (cdr lst)))))

(define (value-at-position lst k)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((= k 1) (car lst))
        (else (value-at-position (- k 1) (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: `(gen-consecutive a b (lambda (x) x))`

Comment: @PetSerAl  I am guessing this is what you mean `(value-at-position filter prime? (gen-consecutive a b (lambda (x) x)) n)` if so that does not work as it says it is a contract violation and is given: #<procedure:.../problemSet5.rkt:77:57>.

Comment: That is not what I mean. You are missing some parenthesis in `value-at-position` call. With your definition it accept two arguments `lst` and `k`, but in your comment your are passing four. BTW in Racket you can use `identity` instead of `(lambda (x) x)`.

Comment: `(value-at-position (filter prime? (gen-consecutive a b identity)) n)`

Comment: @PetSerAl when using `identity` it has the error identity is undefined. I tried looking through racket documentation to try and understand it more but the documentation is really vague

Comment: `identity` can be defined as `(lambda (x) x)` or you can use `values` which for one argument is the same. The whole point is that the function is called for each step and since you just want the from and to values verbatim the function just needs to return the argument. The function supports more fancy stuff like squaring all numbers from a to b by providing a term function.

Comment: @user10336367 Possibly you have only subset of Racket (or some other Racket defined language) imported in, but not full Racket, so you do not have this function. Then just use `(lambda (x) x)`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I am using R5RS. This is what I have down `(value-at-position (filter prime? (gen-consecutive a b (lambda (x) x))) n))` but it is giving me the error of again contract violation saying it expected a real? but instead was given   #<procedure:.../problemSet5.rkt:77:57>

Comment: `f` is the first parameter – `(gen-consecutive (lambda (x) x) a b)`

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 mistakes in your program!
I do NOT have a function prime?, therefore I used odd? instead

```
(define (nth-prime-between a b n)

  ;; missing parenthesis for the function filter
  ;; n is value of the function
  ;; (value-at-position filter odd? (gen-consecutive a b)) n)

  (value-at-position (filter odd? (gen-consecutive a b)) n))

;; kill the parameter f
;;
;; (define (gen-consecutive f a b)
;;   (if (>  a b)
;;       '()
;;       (cons (f a) (gen-consecutive f (+ a 1) b))))

(define (gen-consecutive a b)
  (if (>  a b)
      '()
      (cons a (gen-consecutive (+ a 1) b))))

(define (filter f lst)
     (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((f (car lst))
         (cons (car lst) (filter f (cdr lst))))
        (else
          (filter f (cdr lst)))))

 (define (value-at-position lst k)
     (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((= k 1) (car lst))
         ;; the sequence of (- k 1) and (cdr lst) is wrong
         ;; (else (value-at-position (- k 1) (cdr lst)))))
         (else (value-at-position (cdr lst) (- k 1)))))

 (define (odd? N)
   (if (= (remainder N 2) 0)
      #f
      #t))

(nth-prime-between 1 10 3)
```

The deeper problem with task is:
When you call (nth-prime-between 1000 10000 2),
you must test 9000 numbers with (prime? n). Probably, it is enough to test 10 numbers.
By the way, there exists intervals of any length with no prime numbers in it.
To test a number N with with prime? you need to know the prime numbers less the (square-root N). Where will you store them?
If it is serious task, you can write a program using the sieve of Eratosthenes with a clever stopping condition.